# Add row to datagridview with DataSource

Tags: datagridview

I have a window application written in C#. I have a datagridview inside it. Here is the code:

```
private List<Tablet> tabletList = new List<Tablet>();
...

private void tabControl1_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
{
    GetTabletList();
}

void GetTabletList()
{
    Tablet newTablet = new Tablet();
    newTablet.xxx = yyy;
    newTablet.xxx2 = yyy2;
    tabletList.Add(newTablet);

    dataGridView.DataSource = tabletList;
    Console.WriteLine(tabletList.Count);
}

public class Tablet
{
    public string xxx { get; set; }
    public string xxx2 { get; set; }
}
```

Everytime I call `GetTabletList()`, the value `tabletList.Count` keep increasing but I can only see 1 row in datagridview. What's wrong?

Comment: can you give some more code? Where do create your tabletList-instance? OnClick of a button? Constructor of the form?

Comment: I have simplified my code for testing, the function `GetTabletList()` will be called everytime I click on the controlTab containing this datagridview, and I put the assignment of `newTablet` inside `GetTabletList()`, it still only shows 1 row (or 2 rows if I add another `newTablet2`), the table just doesnt accmulate.

Answer (score 0):

try `ObservableCollection<Tablet>` in stead of `List<Tablet>`

Comment: I'm not sure wether you understood what I was trying to say. Try using this: `ObservableCollection<Tablet> tabletList = new ObservableCollection<Tablet>()`